# If $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then it has a subsequence such that $\|x_{n_k} - x_{n_{k-1}}\| < 1/2^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

If $X$ is a normed linear space and $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$, then $x_n$ has a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ which satisfies $$\|x_{n_k} - x_{n_{k-1}}\| < \frac 1 {2^k}$$ for every $k > 0$.

Why is this assertion true?

Comment: To start, there exists $n_1$ such that $||x_n-x_m||<1/2$ for every $n,m\ge n_1$. And btw, $n_1\ge n_1$.

Comment: it is not an exercise. i'm just wondering why this is true because i need to verify to myself that convergence of normally convergent series implies that the space is banach. so please provide an answer.

Comment: The definition of a Cauchy sequence is your friend.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159484/a-cauchy-sequence-has-a-rapidly-cauchy-subsequence and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232012/show-that-a-cauchy-sequence-has-a-fast-cauchy-subsequence

Answer (score 1):

The definition of Cauchy sequence begins by saying "for **every** $\varepsilon>0$".  Whatever is true of EVERY positive number is true of $1/2^kn$.

Comment: but this $k$ is dependent on the index of the subsequence in a particular way. how to match these together?

Comment: To follow this up: start with two elements that are within $\frac{1}{2}$, then use one of those to find an element that is $\frac{1}{4}$ within one of those two, etc. Make a subsequence out of these elements in order.

Comment: @Michael Hardy The statement is a bit different tho, you have $d(x_m,x_n)<\epsilon$ there, and $d(x_{n_k}, x_{n_{k-1}})$ here.

Comment: @madmatician : FIRST: What is true of every positive number is true of $1/2^k$. That means there exists $N\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ such that for ALL $n,m\ge N$ we have $\|x_n-x_m\|<1/2^k$.  Just let $n_{k-1}$ be that value of $N$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Let $(a_n)_{n\in N}$ be any monotonically decreasing sequence of positive numbers.  Let $g(1)$ be the least (or any) $n$ such that $\forall n'>n\;(|x_n-x_{n'}|<a_1).$ Recursively, let $g(j+1)$ be the least (or any) $n>g(j)$ such  that $\forall n'>n\;(|x_n-x_{n'}|<a_{n+1}).$ The subsequence $(a_{g(n)})_{n\in N}$ satisfies  $\forall n\;(|x_{g(n)}-x_{g(n+1)}|<a_n)$. In particular we may choose $a_n=2^{n+1}$ for each $n\in N$.